# Entity Framework Profiler: unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlclientfactory'

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, exception, entity-framework-6, profiler

When I use the [Entity Framework Profiler 3.0](https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof) to log the real SQL statement in background, sometimes I give this exception:

Message: unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlclientfactory'.
Source: EntityFrameWork.

I give this error when I run the project in visual studio 2015 debugging mode, it displays a file browser to locate `r5wldbbb.5.cs`. I don't know what's this file and also it doesn't exist in `Entity Framework Profiler` folder. So when I cancel it I give the above exception and raise this error:

**r5wldbbb.5.cs not found.**
You need to find r5wldbbb.5.cs to view the source for the current call stack frame.

However, when I cancel the `Entity Framework Profiler` I don't give this error.

I use these programe:
Visual Studio 2015.
MSSQL Server 2014.
EntityFramework 6.

Any helps appreciated.

Comment: DId you finally fix it ? I have the same issue

Comment: No, I couldn't.

Comment: I did. See my comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it.

The trick is to update the way you get and open the connection to the database:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourContextName"].ConnectionString;    

var connectionFactoryService = (IDbConnectionFactory)DbConfiguration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IDbConnectionFactory);

var DbConn = connectionFactoryService.CreateConnection(connectionString);
```

Let me know if it works for you too :) Also, don't forget to update the EF profiler to the latest version using NuGet.